# Suggested approach to query count of records by Date and populate a histogram chart

Tags: mysql, count

I have a log table with a timestamp (Date) column, and I want to create a histogram to show how many records is added to the table hourly for 7 days.

And the number of entries into the table is random, sometimes just 100s of records in an hour, and sometimes could be 10000+ in an hour.

What would be the best approach to query the data?

Option 1 : Query all records in the last 7 days, then iterate them in code to fill up an array list based on hour.

Option 2 : Do a count query on hourly based, and ran it 24 * 7 = 168 times.

Currently I'm using Option 1, but when the number of entries in the log table is huge, the processing time (and memory usage) is terrible. But is running 168 mysql command a better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 : Return the counts "by hour" from a GROUP BY query

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H') AS yyyy_mm_dd_hh
      , COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM logtable
  WHERE t.dt >= ? 
    AND t.dt <  ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date,'%Y-%m-%d %H')
  ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date,'%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Unfortunately, this query will not return "zero counts" for hours for which there are no rows in logtable. Those would either need to be filled in by the application, or we'd need to write the query differently, using a dimension table so we are guaranteed to get a row returned for every hour.

Having a suitable index, with a leading column of dt will allow MySQL to perform an index range scan operation.

In terms of performance, this likely to be faster than 168 separate queries, and will also be faster than returning a bloatload of rows to the client to be counted.

---

To get the "zero counts" returned, we need a rowsource that will return a row for each hour. If we have a table that can return us a consecutive set of integers from 0 thru 167 we'd be good...

```
 SELECT s.i
   FROM myints s
  WHERE s.i >= 0 
    AND s.i <  168
  ORDER BY s.i
```

With that, we can generate the set of "hour" ranges that we want to check.

```
 SELECT c.d + INTERVAL s.i HOUR AS dt
   FROM (SELECT '2016-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR AS d) c
   JOIN myints s
     ON s.i >= 0 
    AND s.i <  168
  ORDER BY s.id
```

And we can use that as an inline view

```
 SELECT h.dt
      , COUNT(t.dt) AS cnt
   FROM ( SELECT c.d + INTERVAL s.i HOUR AS dt
            FROM (SELECT '2016-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR AS d) c
            JOIN myints s
              ON s.i >= 0 
             AND s.i <  168
           ORDER BY s.id
        ) h
   LEFT
   JOIN logtable
     ON t.dt >= h.dt
    AND t.dt <  h.dt + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  GROUP BY h.dt
  ORDER BY h.dt
```

Comment: Best of both world, still, the time it take to process is longer than I hoped, but much better than before.

Comment: @AndChan: To go any further with improving performance we'd really need to see the EXPLAIN output, for the query, along with pertinent parts of the table definition (storage engine, primary key, indexes/indexed columns, rowlength). Frequently questions like this come with restrictions such as "can't add indexes" and "can't make changes to the table definitions". For blazing fast performance of the query, we'd really need pre-aggregated results, the heavy lifting of getting counts by hour calculated ahead of time, stored in a table, would be done offline. Our online query would be blazing fast.